# Order by not working on calculated columns if order by applied on multiple columns

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql version 9.6. I want to apply order by on a calculated column with one existing column. If I apply order only on calculated column then it working fine but it is throwing error when one more column is added in order by clause.

Error is:

```
ERROR:  column "column_name" does not exist
```

Here are the queries:

Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "student" (
    "age" numeric(2) NOT NULL ,
    "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL);
```

Insert Data:

```
insert into student values(22, 'Vikram');
insert into student values(12, 'Bhagirath');
insert into student values(12, 'SKR');
```

Query:

```
Select *, 
       CASE WHEN age>18 then 'Adult' ELSE 'MINOR' end  as category 
from student 
order by category;
```

The above query is working fine. If I add `name` to order by clause then it throw error:

```
Select *, 
       CASE WHEN age>18 then 'Adult' ELSE 'MINOR' end  as category 
from student order by (category,name);
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  column "category" does not exist
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, but it was just an example to explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove those parentheses around the columns for the `group by`:

```
Select *, CASE WHEN age>18 then 'Adult' ELSE 'MINOR' end  as category 
from student 
order by category, name;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/BHQ36816