# order by with multiply custom name in brackets failed

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

It failed when I put the column name in brackets:

```
select id as "gid", coalesce(name, 'apple') as "name" 
from test 
order by ("gid", "name") desc
```

And I want the above code to achieve the same result as this:

```
select id as "gid", coalesce(name, 'apple') as "name" 
from test 
order by (id, name) desc;
```

And it will work fine with:

```
select id as "gid", coalesce(name, 'apple') as "name" 
from test 
order by "gid" desc, "name" desc
```

So why can't Postgres find "gid"? And is `order by (a, b)` the same as `order by a,b`?

Here is my create sql:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( "id" serial NOT NULL, "name" text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id") );
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('Apple');
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('Orange'); 
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('Pear');
```

Comment: `order by ("gid", "name")` is not a valid syntax

Comment: but this will ok `with test_with as (select id as "id", coalesce(name, 'apple') as "name" from test )
select * from test_with order by (test_with."id", test_with."name");`

Comment: putting parentheses around columns is completely useless (it creates a **single** column with an anonymous record type), invalid syntax in other databases and might even [lead to errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56864089) - don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres allows column references in the `ORDER BY`.

However, it does not allow *expressions* on column references.  The parentheses turn the `ORDER BY` keys into an expression, specifically one that creates an anonymous record.

If you want to do this, you can use a lateral join to define the columns:

```
select v.*
from test t cross join lateral
     (values (id, coalesce(name, 'apple'))) v("gid", "name") 
order by (v."gid", v."name") desc;
```

The aliases are needed in the `order by` only because `"name"` is defined in both tables.

Comment: Simply removing the useless parentheses would be a better solution. I don't think jjamo actually _want_s an anonymous record there (I wouldn't be surprised if she/he doesn't even know that there is such a thing in Postgres)